# Django password problems

Tags: django, django-forms

I'm using a modelform for User like so:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password','email',)
```

but the password field shows up as a regular textfield, not a password input.  How do I make sure it shows a password field?

I tried this:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length = 15, min_length = 6)
    password = forms.PasswordInput() 
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password','email',)
```

but that doesn't work either.

I'm also trying to add a confirm password field like so, but this causes no fields to be displayed:

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length = 15, min_length = 6)
    password = forms.PasswordInput()
    cpassword = forms.PasswordInput()

    def clean(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['cpassword']!=self.cleaned_data['password']:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords don't match")

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password','cpassword','email',)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You're missing the difference between form fields and form widgets. The widget is the HTML representation of the field. If you're on Django 1.2 you can use this syntax:

**EDIT:** Update to include confirm password

```
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password','email',)
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
        }
```

Comment: thanks, I didn't know you could do that

would it be the same thing for confirm password?

Comment: Since that field isn't in the model, you'll need to declare it separately...I'll update my answer

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand why I have to specify the PasswordInput as a widget to a CharField.  They are both forms aren't they?  Why can't I just use PasswordInput?

Thanks!

Comment: There's a distinction between form fields and form widgets. You can think about it this way -- The form field decides how python should work with the field (validation, type, etc). The form widget is the HTML representation. In your case you want to deal with character input, but you want the HTML to show a password input.

Comment: On line three you have `form` as singular, and I'm assuming it's supposed to be plural