# How to create Password Field in Model Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to create password as password field in views.

**models.py:**

```py
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

**forms.py:**

```py
class UserForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

Comment: here, this will answer your question http://stackoverflow.com/a/3715382/997562

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create password input field in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324432/how-to-create-password-input-field-in-django)

Comment: 50 is too small for modern hashing algorithms and long salt. I think you need and least 256

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Use widget as `PasswordInput`

```
from django import forms
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

Comment: I tried this but the password no longer renders in the fields. the field always looks empty

Comment: working for me on (based) createView but not updateView : I can see the dots of the "blurred" field on createView. But like @Freator, field remains empty even with initial overriding on updateView

Answer (score 41):

You should create a `ModelForm` ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/)), which has a field that uses the `PasswordInput` widget from the forms library.

It would look like this:

### models.py

```
from django import models
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

### forms.py (not views.py)

```
from django import forms
class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        widgets = {
        'password': forms.PasswordInput(),
    }
```

For more about using forms in a view, see [this section of the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view).

Answer (score 13):

See my code which may help you.
models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Customer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    instrument_purchase = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    house_no = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_line1 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address_line2 = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from models import *

class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ('name', 'email', 'password', 'instrument_purchase', 'house_no', 'address_line1', 'address_line2', 'telephone', 'zip_code', 'state', 'country')
```

Comment: PasswordInput() with the brackets

Answer (score 0):

I thinks it is vary helpful way.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
class User(models.Model):
    user_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from Admin.models import *
class User_forms(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model= User
        fields=[
           'user_name',
           'password'
            ]
       widgets = {
      'password': forms.PasswordInput()
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'password', 
                  'first_name', 'last_name', 
                  'email']
        widgets = {
            'password': forms.PasswordInput()
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).