# How to get django password hashing functionality in a modell mid-project

Tags: django, authentication, django-models, passwords

I have a project in django and I am trying to add a new field, password, to an existing model. However, I don't want to make any changes that would break the DB or the backend.

All I want to add to the model is just password functionality (with hashing).

How would I go about this?

PS: This model is completely separate from my User model

Comment: Is this a password in your project’s user model? Or is it some other password field within another model?

Comment: It's on another model

Comment: You will need to use a widget for a CharField. The accepted answer here will help you.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523263/how-to-create-password-field-in-model-django

Comment: It doesn't give password hashing functionality, and I am not trying to create a form. I am trying to provide password functionality to a model. Thanks for your help btw

Comment: Can you use any functionality from the `hashlib` library?

Comment: How will I be able to integrate it...sorry, I'm not familiar with that library

Comment: I haven’t ever needed to do this on another model myself, so I’m not sure I can help you any further. I did just Google it however and found this which might be useful. https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1330/

Comment: I used django-fernet-fields...thank you for your help though