# Why are password fields not rendering in the registration page? Django

Tags: python, django

I'm creating a form but the fields to input passwords are not appearing. I can only see the values to input first name, last name and email address. Please any help I would really appreciate it. The code works as following:

First there is a model in where there are the 5 values that I want to be printed. Then the form values are printed individually in the HTML code.

HTML code:

```
<div class="card o-hidden border-0 shadow-lg my-5">
    <div class="card-body p-0">
      <!-- Nested Row within Card Body -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-5 d-none d-lg-block bg-register-image"></div>
            <div class="col-lg-7">
                <div class="p-5">
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <h1 class="h4 text-gray-900 mb-4">Create an Account!</h1>
                    </div>
                    <form class="user" method="POST">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                              {{ form.first_name }}
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                {{ form.last_name }}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                          {{ form.email }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 mb-3 mb-sm-0">
                              {{ form.password1 }}

                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                {{ form.password2 }}

                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-user btn-block">Register Account</button>
                        <hr>
                        <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-google btn-user btn-block">
                            <i class="fab fa-google fa-fw"></i> Register with Google
                        </a>
                        <a href="index.html" class="btn btn-facebook btn-user btn-block">
                            <i class="fab fa-facebook-f fa-fw"></i> Register with Facebook
                        </a>
                    </form>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <a class="small" href="forgot-password.html">Forgot Password?</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <a class="small" href="login.html">Already have an account? Login!</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

forms.py:

```
class CreateUserForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        widgets = {
            'first_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'First Name'}),
            'last_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}),
            'email': EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Email Address'}),
            'password1': PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Password'}),
            'password2': PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Repeat Password'}),
        }
        fields = '__all__'
```

models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password1 = forms.CharField()
    password2 = forms.CharField()
```

Comment: Why are you ***not*** using built-in auth user model?

Comment: because the css gets deleted

Comment: For your model, you are using form fields! Change that to model fields that may do the job for you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is are you using the right `User` model when you defining it in your Form Meta's model attribute:

```
from .models import User


class CreateUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        widgets = {
            'first_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'First Name'}),
            'last_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}),
            'email': EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Email Address'}),
            'password1': PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Password'}),
            'password2': PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Repeat Password'}),
        }
        fields = '__all__'
```

To be honest, it is best to use Django's [built-in `User` model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) or [customized version of the User model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model). If you use Django's built-in model, then you can simply use [`UserCreationForm`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.forms.UserCreationForm), which provides user creation, password validation, password hashing etc.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class CreateUserForm(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = get_user_model()
        widgets = {
            'first_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'First Name'}),
            'last_name': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Last Name'}),
            'email': EmailInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Email Address'}),
            'password1': PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Password'}),
            'password2': PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control form-control-user', 'placeholder': 'Repeat Password'}),
        }
        fields = ['first_name', 'last_name', 'email']
```

Comment: it works but now the password fields don't appear with any CSS. This is very weird...

Answer (score 0):

probably error there, it should be

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField()
    last_name = models.CharField()
    email = models.EmailField()
    password1 = models.CharField()
    password2 = models.CharField()
```

also check this answer [How to create Password Field in Model Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17523263/how-to-create-password-field-in-model-django)

Comment: Still not working. i've tried putting models.values and also putting PasswordInput as a widget in forms.py

Somehow the password fields still don't appear.